# mainBundlePath is Null for node package

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, coreml

I am using the package react-native-coreml and running into this error at startup.

My intention is to use this package to use a CoreML package in my react native app. I am running this within EXPO if that makes any difference.

I can't even run the app. These two errors are together.

```
Unable to start your application. Please refer to https://expo.fyi/no-registered-application for more information.
```

and

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNCoreML.mainBundlePath')
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
```

Obviously the first error isn't useful, just including for thoroughness.

My implementation is as follows:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import FaceScanner from './FaceScanner';
import { classifyImage } from "react-native-coreml";

const Onboarding = () => {
    const [imageURL, setImageURL] = useState('');
    const [tested, setTested] = useState(false);

    console.log(imageURL)
    if (imageURL !== '' && !tested) {
        async () => {
            // const { label, confidence } = await classifyImage(imageURL, './model.mlmodelc')
            setTested(true);
            console.log("The image is a " + label + ". I think. ")
        }
    }
...
```

**edit** I have ejected from expo as per a comment's suggestion. I am now encountering these errors.

```
BUNDLE  ./index.js 
ERROR    TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNCoreML.mainBundlePath')
LOG      Running "main" with {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}
ERROR    Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
```

Comment: I am having a similar problem. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68416430/unable-to-use-rnfs-to-read-a-file-despite-providing-an-existing-path

Answer (score 0):

react-native-coreml is a library with native extensions that do not work in the expo managed workflow currently. [you can read about the managed workflow limitations in the expo docs](https://docs.expo.io/introduction/why-not-expo/).

if you'd like to use it, run `expo eject` and build the project in xcode

Comment: See edit to original post for follow up. Thanks